# Sum values in jQuery object by key

Tags: jquery, each, jquery-csv

I have a csv file converted to a jQuery object using jQuery CSV (https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv/).

Here is the code for that:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/path/myfile.csv",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {
        // once loaded, parse the file and split out into data objects
        // we are using jQuery CSV to do this (https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv/)

        var data = $.csv.toObjects(data);
    });
```

I need to sum up values by key in the object. Specifically, I need to add up the bushels_per_day values by company.

The object format is like so:

```
    var data = [
        "0":{
            beans: "",
            bushels_per_day: "145",
            latitude: "34.6059253",
            longitude: "-86.9833417",
            meal: "",
            oil: "",
            plant_city: "Decatur",
            plant_company: "AGP",
            plant_state: "AL",
            processor_downtime: "",
        },
        // ... more objects
    ]
```

This isn't working:

```
    $.each(data, function(index, value) { 
        var capacity = value.bushels_per_day;
        var company = value.plant_company.replace(/\W+/g, '_').toLowerCase();
        var sum = 0;
        if (company == 'agp') {
            sum += capacity;
            console.log(sum);
        }
    });
```

It just returns the value for each with a leading zero by company:

0145

0120

060

etc.

How can I do this?

Comment: Your data contains strings, you need to use `parseInt()` to convert it to numbers.

Comment: Is that `"0"` the actual property? If so, that's not a valid array... arrays dont have key/value pairs, objects do.

Comment: @timeJV - it's an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `parseInt()` to convert the strings to numbers. Otherwise`,`+` does string concatenation instead of addition.

Also, you need to initialize `sum` outside the loop. Otherwise, your sum gets cleared every time, and you're not calculating a total.

```
var sum = 0;
$.each(data, function(index, value) { 
    var capacity = parseInt(value.bushels_per_day, 10);
    var company = value.plant_company.replace(/\W+/g, '_').toLowerCase();
    if (company == 'agp') {
        sum += capacity;
        console.log(sum);
    }
});
```

Comment: Barmar - yours is the closest - unfortunately I can't upvote you yet. This is returning the sum on each iteration. For example, it returns 145, 195, 255, ... 740 (which I know is the total). How can I grab just that final total?

Comment: So obvious - just console.log(sum) outside of the loop. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You are using a local variable `sum` inside `$.each`, which value is reassigned at every iteration, and your variable `bushels_per_day` is `string`typed, so JS just concatenate it's value with `sum` value

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dopg8bzf/). It worked for me